# HTML5 offline support and how to do synchronize with backend database

Tags: html, offline-caching, offline-mode, offline-browsing

I am new to HTML5,very sorry if my question sounds silly to you. I want to understand HTML5 offline capacity. AIM is that application developed will save data in local database (browser) and when application is online the changes will be sent to the server for synchronization,similarly local database will be synchronized with remote database periodically or server will push changes to client. I was reading about HTML5 web databases,but I found that it is deprecated. There is one more support available called as IndexDB. can any one please tell me to accomplish this task which one I should focus? Is it possible with HTML5 as of now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I am not 100% sure what you are after.

Here is some quality reading information on these topics.

---

**Storage**:

[Dive Into HTML5 Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) provides a lot of useful information on localStorage.

localStorage works as `key : value` so it is quite easy and nice to use.

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

---

**Offline Caching:**

I would suggest reading up on using an `appcache`.

[Dive Into HTML5 Offline](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html) provides a lot of useful information on this.

---

**Updating your database:**

As for updating your data base you would need to send the data from the `client` to the `server` the most simple way of doing this would be having your server accept a `HTTP POST` from the web page.

Take a look at the [jQuery POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). The best way to do this would probably be to create an array of your localStorage and `POST` the array to the server. You could have a look at formatting this as [JSON](http://json.org/) or XML etc.

Your web server here would have to accept the `HTTP POST` and then have logic to handle the data that is provided from the client. E.g: Add it to / update your server side DB.

---

Note that [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) is now open source and on [GitHub](https://github.com/diveintomark/diveintohtml5)

Comment: @Marrowmaw..The storage API helps in storing data as key value pair. This is fine but how to sync this data with backend DB?

Comment: using websql/indexDB is recommended?

Comment: @Rajesh I have updated the answer with some information about using HTTP POST using jQuery. You would also need the WebServer to be able to handle this and update your server side data base with the data you provide.

Comment: I am unsure what you are using server side but you could technically use any DB that you want.